# Google Chart not rendering in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

Does anyone know why this Google Chart won't render in IE 8?  It works fine in other browsers

```
$(function () {
        var trendChartWidth = 670;
             var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', '');
            data.addColumn('number', '');
            data.addRows([
                ['Group 1', 168],
                ['Group 2', 83],
                ['Group 3', 1680]
            ]);
            var options = {
                'title': 'Stuff (Last 30 Days)',
                    'width': 210,
                    'height': 170, 
                    'backgroundColor': '#F2F2F2', 
                     colors: ['#94b709', '#4f4840', '#bcbcbc'], 
                     chartArea: { left: 10, top: 30, width: '100%', height: '75%' }, 
                     legend: { position: 'none' }
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartTest'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
        });
```

This is my chart div:

```
<div id="chartTest" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dmaXc/6/

Comment: Any javscript/console errors? This is a bit vague.

Comment: It's totally vague.  No errors in js or console.

Comment: @nathanhayfield i've removed the line.  it is for other functionality and not relevant to this.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working ok on browserstack but not when I run my local IE 9 in IE8 mode

Comment: It probably works in real IE8.  IE9 in IE8 mode sometimes misreports its capabilities.  IE8 doesn't support SVG, so Google Charts is supposed to fall back to VML for IE8, but it won't do that for IE9 in IE8 mode.  I believe there's a way to fix that, but I can't remember, or I'd put it in an answer.

Answer (score -1):

'width': 210,
                    'height': 170, 
                    'backgroundColor': '#F2F2F2',

Don't put single code in width and height and backgroundColor.
Use like below syntax

width: 210,
height: 170, 
backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',